# Squirrel.Windows incremental update not working

Tags: wpf, squirrel.windows

Our app just doesn't want to do an incremental update. We build the app entire week and make build for production on Monday.

However, our updating the app uses only full nupkg, not the small update nupkg.

Is it a issue that the version jumps more than one number? Here are the RELEASES:

```
*8B3B649704D6530ADA354FE8FCFA2E7D2 MyAPP-1.1.9627-delta.nupkg 1402520
KLK9CA610BD3AE0743CB7E8B97FB9450B MyAPP-1.1.9627-full.nupkg 96907884
HHC6604006E1ACAA31DF1454BD265EF6E MyAPP-1.1.9653-delta.nupkg 2150036
8D93FD14A152C7D95E96EF3603A214B21 MyAPP-1.1.9653-full.nupkg 96921305*
```

Comment: `major.minor.patch` is the version format. Patch number can be anything, it doesn't matter as long as its higher than previous one in the same `major.minor`. As long as its higher than previous, none of the segments have any problem. You decides the version.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with bigger version number than +1. Your RELEASES file looks fine, can you share a demo? This should work and I cant help you without demo application that I can reproduced it on.

Comment: We release new version every week. I will post setup of this week version on Monday, then you can install the app and then update it. I don't see anything in logs. My delta files seem a bit small, it's 90MB installation Setup package, and only 2MB delta update package.

Comment: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/34435929/112127532-d4cdb000-8bc5-11eb-824d-e210e716052f.png

It downloads full and delta nupkg...

Comment: @Smooth86 It downloads only delta package and then create new version full package from previous version full package and downloaded delta. It does not download new version full package - just recreate it. Sorry for late answer.

Comment: Petr, please, install this, and it will try to update:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhrhUfMPpwnLi-wtVgM4OIc-dyVYjA?e=Ryzw5n

Comment: @Smooth86 Update was succesfull - delta package was downloaded and then full package was recreated. Where do you see the problem? It takes a few moments to recreate full .nupkg, but thats normal.